# How to fetch the system date with day number

Tags: android

I want to fetch the current system date and according to that I need a particular day number in a year. Please help to get the same.

Ex : 03-04-2014 (dd-mm-yyyy)
I need a currant date = 03-04-2014
and Day of the year = 62nd day of the year.

Here is how my logic looks in Android SDK. I

```
package com.kli.utilizationcalci;
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final EditText editTargethoursyear = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTargethoursyear);
        final EditText editDesignatedholidays = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editDesignatedholidays);
        final EditText editMaxvacationsavailable = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editMaxvacationsavailable);
        final EditText editHourstilldate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editHourstilldate);
        final EditText editVacationsavailed = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editVacationsavailed);
        final EditText editVacationsplanned = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editVacationsplanned);
        final EditText editHoursplannedperweek = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editHoursplannedperweek);
        final EditText editIfsamevacationsminhoursforweek = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editIfsamevacationsminhoursforweek);
        final EditText editIfsamehoursplannedvacationsavailable = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editIfsamehoursplannedvacationsavailable);
        Button buttonCalculate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonCalculate);

    buttonCalculate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                double Targethoursyear = Double.valueOf( editTargethoursyear.getText().toString());
                double Designatedholidays = Double.valueOf( editDesignatedholidays.getText().toString());
                double Maxvacationsavailable = Double.valueOf( editMaxvacationsavailable.getText().toString());
                double Hourstilldate = Double.valueOf( editHourstilldate.getText().toString());
                double Vacationsavailed = Double.valueOf( editVacationsavailed.getText().toString());
                double Vacationsplanned = Double.valueOf( editVacationsplanned.getText().toString());
                double Hoursplannedperweek = Double.valueOf( editHoursplannedperweek.getText().toString());
                double Totalvacations = Vacationsavailed + Vacationsplanned + Designatedholidays;
                double Ifsamevacationsminhoursforweek = 1+1;

                editIfsamevacationsminhoursforweek.setText(String.valueOf(Ifsamevacationsminhoursforweek));
                double Ifsamehoursplannedvacationsavailable = 2+2;

                editIfsamehoursplannedvacationsavailable.setText(String.valueOf(Ifsamehoursplannedvacationsavailable));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Java naming conventions: variable names start with lowercase character. That, and I fail to see how your code is relevant to your question

Comment: Oops, I used a uppercase character.... I will make a correction. I need to get DAY of the YEAR in a double word or some some other constant to use it for further calculation... This is my first program and I am not known to JAVA:)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  int dayOfYear = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);
```

Comment: Do i need to mention under the 'buttonCalculate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()' ? I need a day of the year once the button is clicked and I need to do some computation using the day of the year. and thanx much for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can get date like this and display the date in what ever format you wish and if you want more help then take a look at this .
http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html

```
        mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    mDateDisplay.setText(new StringBuilder().append(mMonth).append("-").append(mDay).append("-").append(mYear).append(" "));
```

Comment: Thank you Darkie. So if I code 'Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);' then Will I have the number of the year in 'DAY_OF_YEAR' field? Or will have to put it in separate double word? Can i use DAY_OF_YEAR for computing purpose?

Comment: @Kiran DAY_OF_YEAR will get you the current year i.e 2014 and you can get it in a textview or a string .it's upto you

Comment: Actual concern in my coding is... I need a day (EX - 1st feb 2014, i.e 32nd day) So I need a 32 in a text to add/multiply down the program.

Comment: @Kiran see the link I have attached with my answer it has all the answers to your questions.